# Finding out if a Window is Resizable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Is there a way to determine whether the active window (not of my process, but a different application) is resizable?

Edit: I would prefer to do this without applescript as it then depends on the application being scriptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Accessibility](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Accessibility/Reference/AccessibilityCarbonRef/). Once you find the window you want to examine, test whether it has the `kAXGrowAreaAttribute` attribute (the value for which would be the grow area itself, a.k.a. the “size box” or [the Windows term] “resize handle”). A window that has one is resizable; a window that doesn't have one is not resizable.

The user will need to have access for assistive devices turned on, but making that happen is easier than scripting unscriptable applications.

**Edit from the year 2011:** Lion killed off size boxes, so now you'll need to [test whether the window's size attribute can be changed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8293914/30461).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check if the "frontmost window" of the target application is resizable! You can perform the scripting request via applescript, scripting bridge or a third party framework!

However, in any case, it's needed that the target application is scriptable and you can access to the "resizable" property (of the "frontmost window" object) via a scripting request!

Comment: Do you know of any third party frameworks that I could use? I would rather not depend on an application being scriptable.

Comment: I don't know any framework that lets you accomplish what you are trying to do whether the target application is not scriptable! Moreover, I don't think there is a better way to do that!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you're getting access to the window. There's a property in AppleScript on Window objects, resizable, that indicates this.